# How to perform SQL Joins and Relations in Sails.js and Waterline?

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

Can anyone guide me on how to setup relational schema & performs joins in [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sails JS Waterline join of multiple models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932095/sails-js-waterline-join-of-multiple-models)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Associations are officially Supported in Waterline

#### Overview

[From the docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations):

> With Sails and Waterline, you can associate models across multiple data stores. This means that even if your users live in PostgreSQL and their photos live in MongoDB, you can interact with the data as if they lived together in the same database. You can also have associations that span different connections (i.e. datastores/databases) using the same adapter. This comes in handy if, for example, your app needs to access/update legacy recipe data stored in a MySQL database in your company's data center, but also store/retrieve ingredient data from a brand new MySQL database in the cloud.

#### Supported Association Types

- [One to Many](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html)
- [Many to Many](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html)

  - [Cross-adapter Dominance](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/Dominance.html)
- [One to One](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoOne.html)
- [One Way](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OneWayAssociation.html)

#### Planned Association Types

- [Through Associations](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ThroughAssociations.html)

---

#### Original Post

> I'm the author of Waterline, the ORM used in Sails. Waterline is brand
>   new and we are adding features all the time. Currently we don't have
>   support for associations but it's next on the roadmap. We worked out
>   an API for associations that I think most people will really like. You
>   can view the work in progress and the proposed API at: [Proposed Sails
>   Associations API][1].
>
> We are going to tackle Associations and Transactions next and hope to
>   have them ready in the next month or so.
>
> In the mean time if you are using the MySQL or PostgreSQL adapters
>   they both expose a raw `.query()` method that allows you to pass in a
>   hand built sql query and have it executed. I totally realize this
>   isn't ideal but should allow you to continue building your app while
>   we get support for associations and joins.
>
> The function signature for the query method is:
>
> ```js
> Model.query(<sql query>, <optional data>, callback);
> ```

Comment: where can one find the documentation for the `Model.query` method?

Comment: It would be nice if custom instance methods were still available when using the model.query method. I assume because the Model.query method  accepts arbitrary sql it makes keeping synch with the model more difficult?

Comment: Because it accepts anything we don't know which collection data we are getting back. You should be able to instantiate a new model instance by doing something like: `var instance = User._model(values)`

Comment: Is it possible to join multiple tables with sails version 0.10.0-rc7 ?

Comment: How can you add parameters in the query, I suppose it is possible with <optional, data> it is possible?

Comment: @particlebanana Please check out [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596718/sailsjs-through-association) Here as it's directly related here. The docs haven't been updated to show how to use through associations. [We need your help](https://www.youtube.com/embed/aYhz5tArAnk?start=9&end=11&safe=active&autoplay=true)

Comment: @avian I updated the answer with the latest Waterline features. Associations and Joins are now officially supported out of the box.

Comment: @particlebanana Please help me - how I can user query builder? I need to create query
`SELECT p.id, p.name, count(c.id) FROM parent p JOIN child c ON c.parent_id=p.id GROUP BY p.id`

Answer (score 6):

The example from particle banana works but should actually use "new" like "var instance = new User._model(values)".  I'm using the following code and it works.

```
Accounts.query(query, function(err, accounts) {
  if (err)
    return fn(err);

  accounts = _.map(accounts, function(account) {
    return new Accounts._model(account);
  });

  fn(null, accounts);
});
```

Comment: Isn't this a blocking statement? You have to wait for that _.map to complete before it continues on. On Node, it would be better to use something like async.js: https://github.com/caolan/async to eliminate blocking code altogether.

Comment: There is no I/O performed in `new Accounts._model()`, so it's not blocking and nothing would be gained from making it asynchronous.