# Complex database queries in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How can I do complex database queries such as joins using Sails.js?

I tried the `generate` method using the command line, it's great and I connected it to my MySQL database and it works great, but now what I need to understand is how I can do complex `SELECT` statements. I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For complicated queries refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977334/810606) by [particlebanana](https://github.com/particlebanana), one of Sails.js core contributors.

As an alternative to perform joins, you can use the [associations](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/associations) branch.