# Sails.js - One to Many mapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapping, one-to-many, sails.js

Is there any way to do relation mapping between models in Sails.js?

Here is what I would like:

Video.js:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    filename: 'STRING',
    length: 'INTEGER',
    watchCount: 'INTEGER',
    extension: 'STRING'
    user: // I wan to reference to my User.js model
  }

};
```

And in my User.js:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true
    },
    password: 'STRING',
    videos: // I would like to have an array of videos after querying a user

  }

};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use associations in sailsJs now by using the v0.10 branch
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21822843/1585332
The mapping would be something like this..

Video.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    filename: 'STRING',
    length: 'INTEGER',
    watchCount: 'INTEGER',
    extension: 'STRING'
    user:{
      model: "user"
    }
  }

};
```

User.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    username: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true
    },
    password: 'STRING',
    videos:{
      collection: "video",
      via: "user"
    },

  }

};
```

Answer (score 7):

Sails.js doesn't support association yet, but they're working on it: 
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124#issuecomment-21690561

Also see: [How to perform SQL Joins and Relations in Sails.js and Waterline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683015/how-to-perform-sql-joins-in-sails-js-waterline)

For now I would just reference ID's and/or use the .query() method.