# How to use association in sails.js + mongodb?

Tags: sails.js

In my case fetching data from two collection usind one id to use another id data not coming properly.

Comment: could you provide more information... sailsjs `0.9.x` doesn't support native associations

Answer (score 2):

You can use the associations in the Sails.js v0.10.
npm install sails@git://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git#v0.10

For the Mongo-db
 npm install sails-mongo@git://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo.git#v0.10

and here is the documentation..
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/ModelAssociations.md

Comment: That link is broken perhaps this is correct: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md