# Sails.js : Joins

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

```
  var obsType = (from lk in db.LookUp
                  join 
                  lt in db.LookUpType
                  on 
                  lk.LookUpTypeId equals lt.LookupTypeId
                  where (lt.FieldName == "OBSType") 
                  && 
                 !(db.OBSSetting.Select(k => k.OBSTypeId)).Contains(lk.Id)
                  orderby
                 (lk.SortOrder ?? decimal.MaxValue)
                 select new LookUpViewModel
                 {
                     Id = lk.Id,
                     Description = lk.Description
                 }).ToList();
  return obsType;
```

This is the MVC LinQ query, How do write this join query in sails js.

Three different models are used here: (LookUpType,LookUp,OBSSetting).

Anyone please guide to do this task.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: The Codeformat to display the Query is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use waterline associations to join tables, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932095/sails-js-waterline-join-of-multiple-models). If it's not working for you, you can go for a raw SQL query ([here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query))