# how to use join to join two table in sails

Tags: sails.js

I know that in sails i can use populate to join two models like describe in this link [Sails model and orm](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-one)
for example i have 2 model:

```
// myApp/api/models/Pet.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    color: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
// myApp/api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    age: {
      type: 'integer'
    },
    pony:{
      model: 'pet'
    }
  }
}
```

then

```
User.find({ name:'Mike' })
.populate('pony')
.exec(function(err, users) {}
```

will return something result like

```
 [{ 
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 21,
  pony: { 
    name: 'Pinkie Pie',
    color: 'pink',
    id: 5,
    createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT-0600 (CST) 
  },
  createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:48:53 GMT-0600 (CST),
  updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:48:53 GMT-0600 (CST),
  id: 1 
 }]
```

in here **pony** is an object and i don't like that. I want return rerult something like this:

```
[{
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 21,
    name: 'Pinkie Pie',
    color: 'pink',
    id: 5,
    createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT - 0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:45:33 GMT - 0600 (CST)
    createdAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:48:53 GMT - 0600 (CST),
    updatedAt: Tue Feb 11 2014 15:48:53 GMT - 0600 (CST),
    id: 1
}]
```

(all of them is property). So i think i would need join in this case. how can i do join ?

Comment: Your expected result object has duplicate keys. How is that supposed to be a JS object or JSON?

Comment: @Sangharsh i will rename it when join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932095/sails-js-waterline-join-of-multiple-models). The answer demonstrates using .populate() in Sails for NoSQL DB's and .query() for SQL DB's.

An additional option, if you are using an SQL DB like MySQL, and this is a query that will be run frequently, is to create a view at DB level. You can find more on creating views in the [MySql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Comment: i think i will create view then

Comment: Yea, it's a good option, then you can create a Model in sails for the DB View and no more nested JSON.