# I want to join two tables(models) in sails 1.12 with a single query

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I want to join Rprojects model with Salesreps model where Rprojects.salesRepID = Salesreps.Id. in Sails.js.

I have tried going over the associations documentation and the collections documentation but just not getting it. So easy in sql.

Comment: I am using Sails.js 1.12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sails JS Waterline join of multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932095/sails-js-waterline-join-of-multiple-models)

Comment: First, the answer you refer to is prior to the release of sails.js which changes many function and attributes (ie INT is not longer an attribute). What I am trying to do is actually the sails 1.12 version of                                       
  ( SELECT projID, owner, address, salesRep FROM Rprojects JOIN Salesreps ON Rprojects.salesRepID = Salesreps.Id )                                                        
         but in Sails.js 1.12 / waterline language.